# Moment.js - getting display format or the formatted value from object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, angular-material2

I'm using Angular and Material2 for a project. 

I've got a moment object created this way:

`myDate = moment.utc(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")`;

Then this object is passed as a parameter to a different function which needs to know the formatted date string. 
Logging this object I see, it has got a property: `_f: YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"` and another one: `_i: "2018-01-17 13:51:54"`

 
Is  there a way I could get the value of `_f` or `_i`?

EDIT:

In the end, I want to get  `"2018-01-17 13:51:54"` not really `_f` or `_i`.

EDIT2:

myDate acts as a Moment object inside that function. Namely: I'm extending MomentDateAdapter and overriding  `format(date: Moment, displayFormat: string): string {}` So **date** IS a Moment object. This is used inside Material2 Datepicker.

EDIT3 - some results:
toString: `Wed Jan 17 2018 14:10:53 GMT+0100` 
format: `2018-01-17T14:10:53+01:00` 
toISOString: `2018-01-17T13:10:53.000Z`

Comment: If your object is called obj, doesn't obj._f give the value that you want?

Comment: No, because _f is 'private'.

Comment: moment.format() returns a String => myDate is a String, see https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: In my function, myDate acts as Moment object.

Comment: Then your code is different than what is shown because `format()` returns string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) guide state you can use:

> To print out the value of a Moment, use `.format()`, `.toString()` or `.toISOString()`.

instead of `_i`, while you can use `format` property returned by [`creationData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/) instead of `_f`.

---

After your edit (*In the end, I want to get  "2018-01-17 13:51:54" not really `_f` or `_i`*), you can simply use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```js
let myDate = moment.utc('2018-01-17 13:51:54'); // myDate is a moment object
let cData = myDate.creationData();
console.log( myDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") );
console.log( cData.format );
console.log( myDate.format(cData.format) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it's still not exactly what I want.

Comment: @flow3r sorry, I gave my answer before last 2 edits. Since `myDate` is a moment object, what is your desired output? What do you need to get?

Comment: I want to get the formatting string "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" OR the result of format() "2018-01-17 13:51:54"

Comment: @flow3r Given the a moment object (e.g. `m` in my snippet) why doesn't `m.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")` give you the desired output?

Comment: The object 'm' (or in my case 'myDate' which is converted to a moment object by Angular) is passed as a parameter to a function. In that function, the format string is not known, but as I've noticed, the correctly formatted date is present in '_i' and the formatting string in '_f'

Comment: @flow3r I've updated my snippet. In the first part of my answer I showed how to replace Internal Properties (`_i` and `_f`). I fear I still miss what is exactly your desired output. Moreover what do you mean with  _'myDate' is converted to a moment object by Angular_? Maybe you can share your relevant _Angular_code.

Comment: Oh, you were right, I'm sorry! I missed the point of your answer. That's what I was looking for: myDate.creationData().format - thank you!

Comment: @flow3r don't worry, I'm glad my answer helped! :)

Comment: Helped me a lot :D